# MySQL delete all "child" elements in a hierarchy

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database set-up in a hierarchy style.  There are 4 tables called `pages`, `regions`, `elements`, and `content`.  Pages is at the top, and content is at the bottom.

To simplify:

**pages** has the column:

```
id
```

**regions** has the columns:

```
id
page_id
```

**elements** has the columns:

```
id
region_id
```

**content** has the columns:

```
id
element_id
```

---

I want to be able to delete all the children of pages using just the **page's id**.

So far, I've been able to use a nested select statement to select the bottom content using the page's id, but that doesn't select the elements, regions, or the page.

```
SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE `element_id` IN (
    SELECT `id` FROM `elements` WHERE `region_id` IN (
        SELECT `id` FROM `regions` WHERE `page_id` IN (
            SELECT `id` FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = 1
        )
    )
)
```

Anyway to do this efficiently?  Thanks.

---

Thanks to @Hago and @Churk, here's my final solution (basically Churk's code, a tiny bit modified):

```
DELETE `content`, `elements`, `regions` FROM `content`
JOIN `elements` ON `elements`.`id` = `content`.`element_id`
JOIN `regions` ON `regions`.`id` = `elements`.`region_id` 
JOIN `pages` ON `pages`.`id` = `regions`.`page_id`
WHERE `pages`.`id` = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM content
JOIN elements ON elements.id = content.element_id
JOIN regions ON regions.id = elements.region_id 
JOIN pages ON pages.id = regions.page_id
WHERE pages.id = 1
```

Comment: if u set up the table on delete cascade when you created the tables, it should have deleted everything. But if you do not have delete on cascade, then you made have to create four different delete statement. Hargo posted his answer seconds before mine, but yes his answer is pretty much same as mine.

Comment: Actually if you have delete on cascade, all you have to do is delete pages where pages.id = 1; and the remaining table would have had their rows removed. If you have to ability to setup tables with on delete cascade, here is a reference howto: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0080__Table/FOREIGNKEYONDELETECASCADEONUPDATECASCADE.htm

Answer (score 0):

Inner join could be more efficient than multiple nested subqueries, try this

```
select 
    c.id 
from 
    contents as c 
inner join 
    elements as e on c.element_id = e.id 
inner join 
    regions as r on e.region_id = r.id 
where 
    r.page_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that's probably more efficient than my first query.  However, it doesn't solve the problem of selecting (and then of course being able to delete) all the data and not just the child data.